# Xcode 8- Build Failed when trying to Archive

Tags: ios, xcode

Note: I'm new to xcode / app development.
I made a small text change to an app and trying to archive it to send to iTunes Connect.I changed the device to "Generic iOS Device" like I've read in other threads. Say's "Build Failed" every time.

Is there something I need to do or change when archiving? 
[Build Failed Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HiNq.jpg)

Comment: Is there a error message on the Build Failed? Potentially the signing changed, etc.

Comment: do add the error message in question..

Comment: I uploaded the error message

Comment: Did you try google your error? "xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching" ?